# Libgdx | How to create minimap?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, viewport

I am making a top-down maze game in libgdx, and I use an extendViewport to render the game camera. I am a bit confused on how I would go about creating a minimap. Should I create an extra viewport and camera for the minimap? I am still new to the whole viewport/camera thing. Thanks!

Comment: This is too broad a question for this site. I'd suggest asking on the LibGDX forums and you'll get several different ideas for approaching it. As opposed to the advice in the answer below, I would absolutely create a second camera and viewport so you can treat the minimap as its own screen and not worry about cropping anything before drawing it. But I wouldn't necessarily try to use the Viewport class and a Stage to do it, as it may be cumbersome to correctly implement all of Viewport's methods for a non-centered viewport.

Comment: If you are using stage2D to layout your UI, you might consider drawing your minimap to a FrameBuffer, and creating an Image out of the FrameBuffer's texture to be placed into your UI. But that would still require a unique camera for the minimap. Trying to draw a minimap using the same camera as the rest of your scene is a recipe for banging your head on the wall many times, imho. :)

Comment: @Tenfour04 So, how would I go about drawing it to a frameBuffer? I'm sorry for all the questions. I also want to exclude certain things from the minimap, such as the player. The only thing on the minimap should be the tilemap.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I guess part of why i'm so confused is that I don't understand this; If I create a new viewport, how does it know what is effected by the viewport? How would everything I render in the spritebatches also be in the viewport?

Comment: The output of a shader is stretched to fill whatever the active viewport is. A camera's combined view and projection matrix is used by SpriteBatch's shader to convert world coordinates into "viewport coordinates" (where the visible area is a 2x2 "square" centered at origin) which is stretched to fit the active viewport.

Comment: So your render method would be something like: 1) Apply viewport of the whole screen (or a FitViewport if you don't care about black bars). 2) Draw your game view with a game camera's combined matrix set on SpriteBatch. End sprite batch. 3) Apply the viewport for the minimap. 4) Draw your map using the minimap camera's combined matrix set on the SpriteBatch.

Comment: If you're using a Viewport subclass to manage your viewport, you apply it with `viewport.apply()`. This is done automatically in `stage.draw()` if you're using Stage. If you want to manage it directly, you can use `Gdx.gl.glViewport(x, y, width, height)` where the coordinates are in screen pixels.

Comment: @Tenfour04 So, I would have to draw all my stuff in two spritebatches? 1 that will set it's projection matrix to my game camera, and 1 that will set it's projection matrix to the minimap camera?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113776/discussion-between-wyatt-and-tenfour04).

Comment: There's no reason to use a second batch. Just repeatedly use the same one with different matrices.

Comment: @Tenfour04 But I will have to essential render the same sprites twice, just different matrices on both renders?

Comment: @Tenfour04 So I should set the camera size to the world size for the minimap, does it need to use a viewport of its own? If so, how would I scale a view port down to 1/8 of the screen, in the top right corner of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Wyatt, the minimap should certainly not be just a smaller version of your entire game viewport. The reason is it has different functionality and look compared to the game viewport. Instead, the minimap should be an Actor on the Stage, which takes in the layout of your map to draw itself and the x and y percentage of your camera's position and size relative to the maze to indicate on the minimap what the player currently sees. If it's at all possible, I suggest you stick with 1 camera and 1 viewport for your entire project unless you are intimately familiar with libgdx. You'll save yourself a ton of time and frustration. Good luck

Comment: Unless the world is highly dynamic, I'd go for this option too: rendering a background texture and a few points of interest saves a lot of rendering time, which you can dedicate to adding other element to your game with more user-value.